# Is there a way to test if a string is encrypted in perl?

Tags: perl, encryption

I was wondering if there is a way to "test" to see if a particular string is encrypted or not.
I am using Crypt::CBC to encrypt a password with Rijndael.

As it stands my script has a "switch" that is either set as 0 or 1 that tells the script weather or not the password needs to be passed through the decrypt phase in order to be read.

I would like to eliminate that phase if I could.

The reason is I am trying to prevent the users of script from possibly prsenting the script with a situation where the password is encrypted but the "switch" was set to 0 meaning not encrypted because this would create a huge "trainwreck".

Comment: It shouldn't be possible.  Something could be encrypted, or it could just be a random pile of gobbledegook... as an aside, Chrome's spell checker actually knows how to spell gobbledegook, wow.

Comment: What if my password actually happens to look like {a password encrypted with Crypt::CBC}?

Comment: I see, so I probably have the best solution there is for my circumstances?

Comment: Cameron's answer below is probably a good guess; it will be right most of the time.  But someone can always provide an unencrypted string that *looks* like one.

Comment: @El Yobo: That's why I said "probably" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your apps so passwords are only stored encrypted. confusion gone.

Comment: True if I just remove the option that would make very simple. I like that approach.

Comment: The only reason I was going to have the option in the first place was to prevent a user from confusing the script. As long as they don't go tampering with the registry keys I will be good.

Comment: Of course, this is far from the only reason for solely using encrypted (or, better, hashed) password storage...

Answer (score 1):

Rijndael has a block size of 128-bits so the output will always be a multiple of this.

If the encrypted passwords are hex-encoded then that will give you strings that are a multiple of 32 characters. In fact, with the IV added, the strings will always be at least 64 characters: 128 bits of IV followed by 128 bits of ciphertext block 1.

You could therefore look for strings of the right length that contain only `[0-9a-f]`. They are *probably* encrypted because I suspect few people can use a 64-character string of randomness as their real password.

If they're base64 encoded then the strings will be a different length, obviously.

This doesn't guarantee that you can always detect an encrypted password but it's probably not too bad.

Comment: hmmm so little regex magic? Well its a place to start. Thanks for the help.

Comment: my key I use for encryption is a 64 Character hex string. Even with something like that does Rinjdael always have a block size of 128? or does it vary by the key?

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard the block size for AES is fixed but Rijndael can be any multiple of 32 bits up to 256. Block size is not affected by key size.

Comment: Few people can (successfully) use a 64-character string of randomness as their password, but `deadbeef` x 8, `0123456789abcdef` x 4, or even `a` x 64 are all passwords which would be manageable by a human while also passing any trivial "looks like an encrypted password" test.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't claiming that this approach would be correct in all cases; just that it may be sufficient for the OP's purposes. I agree that in general there is no way to tell if a particular string is encrypted data or just random (or maybe carefully crafted) data.